# PHP script for adding prefix to sku when duplicate in .csv

Tags: php, csv, echo, fgetcsv

At the moment I have a script that will remove the row in my csv when it has already seen the sku before.

Here is the script:

```
    <?php
// array to hold all unique lines
$lines = array();

// array to hold all unique SKU codes
$skus = array();

// index of the `sku` column
$skuIndex = -1;

// open the "save-file"
if (($saveHandle = fopen("unique.csv", "w")) !== false) {
    // open the csv file
    if (($readHandle = fopen("original.csv", "r")) !== false) {
        // read each line into an array
        while (($data = fgetcsv($readHandle, 8192, ",")) !== false) {
            if ($skuIndex == -1) {
                // we need to determine what column the "sku" is; this will identify
                // the "unique" rows
                foreach ($data as $index => $column) {
                    if ($column == 'sku') {
                        $skuIndex = $index;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if ($skuIndex == -1) {
                    echo "Couldn't determine the SKU-column.";
                    die();
                }
                // write this line to the file
                fputcsv($saveHandle, $data);
            }

            // if the sku has been seen, skip it
            if (isset($skus[$data[$skuIndex]])) continue;
            $skus[$data[$skuIndex]] = true;

            // write this line to the file
            fputcsv($saveHandle, $data);
        }
        fclose($readHandle);
    }
    fclose($saveHandle);
}
?>
```

This works fine but I am starting to need the content that is deleted.

What i need now, is to modify the code to add the same prefix to all duplicate sku's as there will only be 2 of the same sku.

I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Adding a prefix to duplicates

This will add a prefix to any duplicate SKU and will then store it into the unique CSV output, e.g. `XYZ123` becomes `duplicate-XYZ123`.

Change:

```
if (isset($skus[$data[$skuIndex]])) continue;
```

to:

```
if (isset($skus[$data[$skuIndex]])) $data[$skuIndex] = 'duplicate-' . $data[$skuIndex];
```

### Fixing the duplicate header row

Add `continue;` after `fputcsv($saveHandle, $data);` Inside `if ($skuIndex == -1) {`. Because `fputcsv(...)` appears twice in the loop, it will be run twice on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. before I mark as solved would can you help me with one more thing. I think there maybe an error in my original script as it duplicates the headers. so the first two rows are headers

Comment: Just tried it and it is perfect. Thanks for the extra help :)